# How can I fix the Zero Division Error for a limit of a function with a singular point?

Tags: python, function, math, limit, equation

I am trying to avoid zero division error for the limit

`f(u) = 1/(1-u) as u tends to 1^{-}`, then `f(u) tends to +oo (inf)`

My goal is for the function u to approach but not reach zero.  And I will add the `1/(1-u)` function that satisfies this limit condition above to my equation that is described in another Python function. I've coded this limit in two different ways, but it gives the following error.

**How can I avoid this error and still add this function to my equation?**

My first way to define limit:

```
class F():
   def source(self):
      self.f = 1 / (1 - self.u)
      self.limit_f = limit(self.f, self.u, 1, '-')
```

ERROR:

```
<ipython-input-13-c16795f88d58>:18: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  self.f = 1 / (1 - self.u)
```

The second way:

```
class F():
   def source(self):
      self.f = 1 / (1 - self.u)
      if (self.u < 1).all():
         self.limit_f == limit(self.f, self.u, 1, '-')
      if (self.u == 1).all():
         self.f == oo
```

ERROR:

```
<ipython-input-13-c16795f88d58>:18: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  self.f = 1 / (1 - self.u)
<ipython-input-13-c16795f88d58>:29: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  self.f = 1 / (1 - self.u)
```

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!

Comment: Surely they `self.u == 1` should be performed _before_ evaluating `1 / (1 - self.u)`?  That seem so obvious perhaps I am missing something - not a Python programmer, and have no idea what `1^{-}` means.

Comment: `limit` is not defined in the first class example.  Where does this function come from ?

Comment: also,  how are you passing the variable into the class without an `__init__(self, x)` method ?

Comment: 1^{-} means that u approaching 1 from its left. You can think of it as only 1. I believe that it is not a real issue. When I first perform self.u == 1, unfortunately, I get the same error.

Comment: finally,  there is no issue with this problem as u -> inf the fraction -> 0 which is handled in a well behaved manner by the computer. The problem, if any, would arise when u -> 1 which would create a division by zero...

Comment: D.L. - I did not pass the variable __init__. I have all of the necessary structures, but I did not write them down because it is a long code pattern and it could hide my real problem. I defined -limit- in the first class example as well.

Answer (score 0):

The first line executes the error, before you try to catch it in the second line. One variant to solve this would be to use a mask

```
f = np.ones_like(u)*np.inf          # default to infinite value
singular = u==1                     # find out where infinity occurs
f[~singular] = 1/(1-u[~singular])   # compute value where not infinity
```

Comment: Lutz Lehmann- Thank you for your interest. I think your suggestion worked! I'm not sure because I got another error from one of the next lines. Does this mean that there are no errors in the previous lines?

Comment: There should not be further lines necessary for the computation of `f`. It should be usable for plots or other calculations as it is,  as long as these accept inf values.

Comment: I could not explain clearly, sorry. I got an error from a sum that should also be in the equation. It's not about f. So, I can continue with this definition of f. Thank you for your answer. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax makes no sense (unless you are using some libraries like `numpy` or something else you didn't mention):

```
  if (self.u < 1).all():
```

Calling `all()` on boolean condition will result in `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all'`

If you are working with floating points the comparison to 0 does not make too much sense neither (due to floating point representation error). You should rather define an `epsilon` for which you would define conditions on "how close" to the 0 you allow it to be.

Regarding the "limit" I'd suggest to go with this approach (which is an overkill, see comment in the code...but since you didn't explain very clearly what you are aiming at):

- keep passing increasing values for `u`
- except on division error and then assign the "limit"
- do further processing
- since an error is raise your `f` will keep the previous (valid) value

```py
try:
    self.f = 1 / (1 - self.u)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    self.limit = self.u # This is the "first" value of `u` which causes the error, but it boils down to u being 1 or 1.0, otherwise it won't happen
```

Take a look at this example (in python 3.11):

```py
x = 1 / (1-10e1000000) # 10e1000000 is quite a big number
print(x) # -0.0 <class 'float'>
```

Comment: Gameplay- thanks for your interest. My main aim is to plot the behavior of u in time, but I could not pass this limit error. I need to define this function with this limit, and I need to add it to my equation that is defined within for loops.  And, yes, I use numpy. I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this does not appear to be a problem at all as u-> infinity.

take this simple function (no need for a class).

```py
def f(u):
    f = 1 / (1-u)
    return f


u = 10000000000000000

y = f(u)
print(y)
```

1. this is completely well behaved for large values of u.
2. the only issue would arise as u -> 1, in which case the denominator would -> 0 and f would become infinite.

This would be the only case needed to be handled (u=1).